# retrieving of specific file type from sub directory

Tags: c#

I have a Winforms application. In it I have a Folderbrowser, textbox1 and two button control.

Inside my folder I have many sub folders, each hahing have more sub folders. I want to select files types  from one of named subdirectory and call it on

```
string[] dirs = 
               Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "p*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

and print the file type. Problem I am facing is I am getting file from root directory not from sub- directory.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        } 
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var file = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".html") || s.EndsWith(".mp3") || s.EndsWith(".png"));
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text,"file");


            foreach (var a in dirs)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(a);
            }
            foreach (string item2 in dirs)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item2);

                listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);

            }
            foreach (string item in files)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);

                listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Eh `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` means that you want to search in the top directory only. Looks like you want `SearchOption.AllDirectories`option instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did it last week :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    CheckDirectory("path_to_my_mother_directory");
}

    private void CheckDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        MyLog.LogInfo("Check directory", string.Format("Checking for files in {0} directory", targetDirectory));
        var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (var fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Check subfolders
        var subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            CheckDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    private void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        MyLog.LogInfo("File Found", string.Format("File '{0}' found", path));

        var Fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
        if (Fileinfo.Exists && extentionFilesType.Contains(Fileinfo.Extension))
        {
            MyLog.LogInfo("Check extension file", string.Format("File has a searched extension ({0})", Fileinfo.Extension));
            FilesToInsert.Add(Fileinfo);
        }
        else
        {
            MyLog.LogInfo("Check extension file", "File doesn't has a searched extension");
        }
    }
```

`extentionFilesType` is a List with the researched extensions.